# Identifying counties further than ten miles from bank using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcmap, gps, proximity

If I have the latitude and longitude of all US banks.

How can I identify counties whose center is ten miles or further from any bank using that data?

Answer (score 2):

1. You would first need to extract a Centroid point from each County.  If you have an advanced license you can use the [Feature to Point tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/feature-to-point.htm).  If you don't have an Advanced license add a lat and long field to the County layer, use the geometry calculator to calculate the lat and long values, export the table from the Table View and then use the [XY Table to Point tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/xy-table-to-point.htm) to create a point feature class.
2. Then use the [Buffer Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/buffer.htm) with the None Dissolve option to create a buffer with radius of 9.9999 miles around each county point.
3. Create a new polygon feature class with no fields and create a single simple feature shape that covers every bank and US county.  The feature can be made up of multiple shapes for the lower 48 United States, Alaska, Hawaii and optionally the US territories as long as they are merged into a single feature and kept as simple shapes for performance reasons.
4. Use the [Spatial Join tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) with he polygon feature class created in Step 3 as the Target Feature Class and the county centroid point feature class as the Join Feature Class using the One to Many Option.  This will create identical shapes for every county that cover the entire US and every bank.
5. Use the [Union Tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/union.htm) with the output of step 2 and step 4 as the two input feature classes (which is allowed for all licenses).  Assuming there are 3,172 counties and county equivalents features in both feature classes this will create over 10 million shapes, which is why the county shapes in step 4 need to be identical and simple for performance reasons and to prevent additional shaoes from being created by unnecessary intersections.
6. Do a Select by Attributes of all features where the JOIN_FID and ORIG_FID are the same and use the [Delete Features tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/delete-features.htm) to delete the selection.
7. Use the [Dissolve tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/dissolve.htm) on the remaining features on the Join_FID field, State Name field and County Name field.  This will create a single shape for each county with a single 10 mile radius hole in it around the county centroid.
8. Use the [Spatial Join tool](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/analysis/spatial-join.htm) with the the dissolved county shapes as the Target features to the bank points as the Join features using the One to Many option and the Keep All Records option.

The output of step 8 will include duplicates of each county ring for every bank that fell outside of that county's 9.9999 mile radius and will not include any bank point that fell inside the 9.999 mile radius hole.  This set of features will produce the list of bank and county names you desire.

I would like to point out that while this analysis meets the criteria you specified, a 10 mile radius at the geographic center of any given County may be no where near any populated areas.  This is especially true in the large counties of the western United States.  For example, very few buildings of any kind fall within the 10 mile radius at the geographic center of Riverside County in California where I work.  Out of over 800K buildings in Riverside County only 451 buildings fall in that 10 radius and none of those buildings are banks, so every bank in the US would meet your criteria for Riverside County since there is no reason that any bank should be expected to locate within that radius.

Potentially it would be better to calculate the population density factor for every census tract in the US (population divided by census tract area) and spatially join the centroids of the census tracts to your county layer.  Then you could perform a summary with the county as the case field to find the max population density value and select the centroid of the census tract area with that factor for each county.  This centroid would be much more representative of the county's population center of gravity that requires the services of one or more banks.  Alternatively you might want to use the centroid of a heat map analysis of census tract centroids on the assumption that the largest cluster of the census tract centroids for each county in close proximity to each other best represents the county's population center of gravity.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can

1) get the centroid of the counties (using feature to point or, if you don't have the licence, computing X and Y centroid coordinates that you add as point events.)

2) right click on you centroids and select join > join by location

3) this will create a new file with the centroids of the counties and a field indicating the distance to the nearest bank. You thus need to select by attribute all the counties with a distance that is larger than ten miles.

Remark : check the projection used to make sure that your distance units are relevant.